# How can one rigorously treat integration over jump discontinuities?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Suppose I wish to compute $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^n x \,dx$$

We can imagine that the tangent function goes to $0$, with the exception of the point $\displaystyle \left (\frac{\pi}{4},1 \right )$, which the graph passes through independently of $n$.

[image]

The diagram above shows that intuitively, the 'area' below the tangent function for $x \in \displaystyle \left (\frac{\pi}{4},1 \right )$ goes to zero, and therefore $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan ^n x \,dx = 0$$

In my previous studies of calculus, the idea of integrating over a jump discontinuity was often treated with the following idea, informally.

> "Just pretend that the discontinuity isn't there"

This idea was heavily abused in my studies of partial differential equations eg. Heaviside step function.

When there are a finite number of discontinuities in the limiting function, as in my above example with the tangent function, this is something I can accept. In the context of the above example, one can show that $$\frac{1}{2n+2} < \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan ^n x \,dx < \frac{1}{2n-2}$$ which then leads to a sufficiently rigorous proof that we can in fact 'ignore' the singularity at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

However, I am not entirely convinced that the idea still works when there an **infinite** number of such jump discontinuities. Even worse perhaps is when there are an uncountably infinite number of such discontinuities over a fixed domain of integration.

I only really know Riemann integration, which breaks down in scenarios such as these, so I was hoping for an alternative or perhaps a modification of it.

So in light of this, I have a few questions.

1. Can we still 'ignore' an infinite number of singularities?
2. If we can't, what is an example of a function $f$ with infinite singularities, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, over a fixed domain $D$, such that $\int_{D} f \,dx = \infty$.
3. How can we rigorously treat such integrals?

Comment: Answers to these questions become available when you are using Lebesgue integration theory.

Comment: You are not integrating "over" a discontinuity. Every function that you integrate is continuous.

Comment: @almagest I disagree. $\int_{-1}^{2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx = \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$, which we can assign a Cauchy principal value of $\ln 2$.

Comment: And an isolated jump discontinuity is not a problem even for the Riemann integral anyway.

Comment: You're missing @almagest's point: _Neither of your integrands are discontinuous_. $\tan^n x$ is perfectly continuous for $x\in[0,\pi/4]$ no matter what $n\ge 0$ is. Note that what you want to compute is $\lim_n \int \tan^n x \,dx$, not $\int (\lim_n \tan^n x) \, dx$. Only the latter would give you cause to consider whether you can integrate a discontinuous function.

Comment: @Trogdor I was commenting on your $\tan^nx$ example. The question was not $\int\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)dx$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n(x)dx$ and every $f_n(x)$ is continuous over the relevant interval.

Comment: Fair enough, I understand your point there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly i think you are over complicating a simple matter

There are plenty of ways to show that

$$
*)\,\, \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^n{x}\, dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\tan^n{x}\, dx
$$

One way is uniform convergence from real analysis. That's a more strict rule. But here you can see from the picture you probably wont be able to show that .

So we need to use Lebesgue integrals and theorems regarding measure theory.

One of them is [Dominant convergence theorem][1]

Here we know that $\tan{x}$ is a growing function on $[0,\pi/4]$ so we know that
$\tan^n{x} \le 1$ and also $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}1dx=\frac{\pi}{4}<+\infty$

So that said we know that the equation marked $*$ is true.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Now to answer your questions.

1. Yes. You can ignore infinite number of singularities as long as those singularities are of $\aleph_0$ order.

Why? Because you Lebesgue integral on such domain is 0 because Lebesgue measure of any countable set is 0.

3. We can rigorously treat them by applying definitions of Lebesgue integral , theorems about monotone convergence, dominant convergence, Beppo-Levi theorem,...

In most cases you can show that improper Riemann integral is equal to the Lebesgue integral for all integrand measurable functions . Theorem of measure continuity are of great value there.

In some cases you wont be able to solve improper riemann with proper Lebesgue integral such as $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} dx$.

Comment: You mean functions which are both improperly Riemann integrable and Lebesgue integrable. There are cases where a function is only one or the other, e.g. $\sin(x)/x$ on $[1,\infty)$ or the indicator function of the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: True but integral of indicator function of rationals is not even an improper Riemann integral. Though i agree that $sin(x)/x$ is not lebesgue integrable as it results in $\infty - \infty$. Even though that cannot be defined well, in reimann improper integration that integral has a solution.

Comment: ...Yes, that's what I said, and it's a distinction you missed in your answer. When both make sense, they are the same, but sometimes only one or the other (or neither, for instance with $\int_{-1}^1 1/x dx$) makes sense.

Comment: Yeah i was writing an edit the moment i posted my coment here.
Since you are right even though i personally think that making equal an improper Riemann and Lebesgue integral without prior showing they are the same is nonsense.  So i meant to say what i posted in the edit. But you were right to correct me as i did obviously wrote a wrong thing :)

Comment: FYI, there is in fact a dominated convergence theorem for the Riemann integral which is applicable here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT125B/materials/Luxemburg-Arzela.pdf

Comment: @Bungo I did not know that ! :) Even though that theorem has little value when you look it has stronger conditions than dominated convergence theorem. But such a fun thing to lean ! :))) Thank you

Comment: @daniels_pa: I agree, it does not seem to be an important result (maybe that is why it is not better known) as the Lebesgue version is stronger and is easier to prove (for integration on abstract measure spaces, at least; the hard part is constructing the Lebesgue measure). But it shows that the Riemann integral is not as useless as often asserted, with respect to limit operations!